# How to define macros in order to reuse key-value parameters?

Tags: macros, listings, key-value

I use the `listings` package to typeset code in my document. I have defined a new environment via `\lstnewenvironment` in which I use `\lstset` to set a large number of options through a list of key-values. It looks like the following:

```
\lstnewenvironment{mycodebox}[1][]                                                                                                                      
{
  \lstset{
     key1=val1,
     key2=val2,
     % some more options are set
     #1 % so that it can accept more options
  }
}{}
```

I use this new environment mostly in two  variants where in each variant I need to override some existing (or add new) options. For example:

```
% variant 1
\begin{mycodebox}[newkey=newval, key1=newval]
 % my code
\end{mycodebox}
```

and

```
% variant 2
\begin{mycodebox}[anotherkey=newval, key2=newval]
 % my code
\end{mycodebox}
```

The two variants share a lot of options but they are different. Can I define two macros/commands like `\variant1settings` and `\variant2settigns` that can be used in some way like the following?

```
\begin{mycodebox}[\variant1settings]
 % my code
\end{mycodebox}
```

I know that I can use `\lstset{options...}` to do this before using the environment each time but

1. I don't want the options to run through when I don't specify them before subsequent instances;
2. I want the options to be in the form of a macro (or similar) so that they can be tweaked from one central position.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could use `\newcommand\variantA{\lstset{...}}` and `{\variantA\begin{mycodebox}...\end{mycodebox}}` in the text, but it is slightly less convenient than the syntax you asked for.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, this would certainly work in this context. Thanks for bothering to answer this but maybe I'm looking for something more elegant (and general) if possible at all. Can a macro (or something similar) be used inside the square brackets to specify additional options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expansion of the content of the optional argument #1 has to be postponed, otherwise the macro `\optionstocodebox` is expanded, letting `keyval` macros think its content is a complete key name, which isn't, of course.

Using

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\lstset{numbers=right,language={C},#1}}\x
```

will prevent premature expansion and expands it afterwards.

`\begingroup...\endgroup` is a neat trick to let the redefinition `\x` be forgotten after it's expanded (which is the case at the end of `}}\x`.

To be short: the expansion is prevented first for \lstset, then applied afterwards by calling `\x`.

However, no unexpandable stuff such as `\textbf` or `\textcolor` are allowed without fine-tuning. This could be achieved by a *brute force* `\unexpanded{stuff}` as a key assignment. The second example `\otheroptionstocodebox` shows usage with `\unexpanded` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}


\lstnewenvironment{mycodebox}[1][]                                                                                                                      
{
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\lstset{numbers=right,language={C},#1}}\x
}{}   


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\optionstocodebox}{language={Pascal},numbers=left}%



\newcommand{\otheroptionstocodebox}{language={C},numbers=left,stepnumber=3,numberstyle={\unexpanded{\color{red}\tiny}}}%


\begin{mycodebox}[language={C}]
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}
\end{mycodebox}

\begin{mycodebox}[numbers=left,\optionstocodebox]
program first

BEGIN
WriteLn('Hello World');
END.
\end{mycodebox}


\begin{mycodebox}[language={C},\otheroptionstocodebox]
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}
\end{mycodebox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You provided a good explanation of what's going on (more inline with the title of the question). @TorbjørnT. gave the most elegant way of doing this in the context of `listings`. A tough call for me as to which one I should choose as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

`listings` allow you to define styles that you can apply to individual listings with `style=<stylename>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstdefinestyle{style1}{basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{red}}
\lstdefinestyle{style2}{basicstyle=\scshape\color{blue},frame=single}

\lstnewenvironment{mycodebox}[1][]                                                                                                                      
{
  \lstset{
     basicstyle=\itshape,
     #1
  }
}{}  

\begin{document}
\begin{mycodebox}[style=style1]
This is some text
\end{mycodebox}

\begin{mycodebox}
This is some text
\end{mycodebox}

\begin{mycodebox}[style=style2] 
This is some text
\end{mycodebox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think, the style option is what I 'reinvented' (;-)) by preventing unexpansion. (+1)

Comment: This is certainly the most elegant way of doing this in the context of `listings`. Thanks!

Comment: Once I have defined an ``lstdefinestyle{style1}{blabla}``, can I use it inside ``\lstnewenvironment{mycodebox}`` in combination with ``lstset{}``?  Can I write ``lstset{basicstyle=style1}``? If so/not so, perhaps you could comment on that, if you are so inclined.

Comment: @PatrickT If you look at how `style1` is defined with `\lstdefinestyle`, you'll probably see that setting `basicstyle=style1` doesn't really make sense. `style1` contains `basicstyle` and any other settings you'd like. But I do say in the first sentence that you select a style with `style=<stylename>`, and indirectly what happens in the code is `\lstset{style=style1}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  great thanks! I had missed that opening sentence, apologies.